# Cannot convert value of type '() -> _' to specified type 'NewsAPIResponse'

Tags: swift

I thought my completionHandler returned a value of the type 'NewsAPIResponse', but I don't know how to assign it to a static var. Why is my code throwing an error? Is it not converting? I have checked all other areas of code for debugging. I am not sure whether the problem stems from how I created the completionHandler or not. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

```
 struct Article {

    let site: String
    let title: String
    let date: Date
    let tickers: String
    let image: String

    var siteText: String {
        site
    }
    var titleText: String {
        title
    }
    var tickerText: String {
        tickers
    }
    var dateText: String {
        "\(relativeDateFormatter.localizedString(for: date, relativeTo:Date()))"
    }
    var imageURL: URL? {
        URL(string: image)
    }
}

extension Article: Codable{}
extension Article: Identifiable{
    var id: String{title}
}

struct NewsAPIResponse : Decodable{
    let content: [Article]
}

extension Article {

    func fetchData(completionHandler: @escaping (NewsAPIResponse) -> Void) {
        let url = URL(string: "My API KEY")
    
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL!)

        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                print("Data is empty")
                return
            }

            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            jsonDecoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)

            let apiResponse = try!jsonDecoder.decode(NewsAPIResponse.self, from: data)
            completionHandler(apiResponse)
        }
        task.resume()
    
    }
    
    static var previewData: NewsAPIResponse = { //error is thrown here
        let response = fetchData(){[weak self](apiResponse) in
        }
        return response
    }

}
```

Comment: `fetchData` return nothing, Void, ie `()`. You are still missing the async concept, and you can't transform like that an async into sync (and that's usually a bad idea). `previewData` shouldn't be a static variable.

Comment: How do I access the data in the completion handler then? (ie from the completionHandler(apiResponse) line)

Comment: Also, previewData has to be static because it's contained within an extension.